# How to dynamically change the drawing path in Visio Web Access Web Part

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, rest, visio

I am wondering if there's any way to dynamically change the drawing shown by a visio web access web part. I have multiple drawings I want to show on a page based on what users click on the page.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've looked in to this some hours ago. There is a way to get the drawings URL by javascript, but at a quick glance I found no possiblity to set it